# Transferring/re-using automation scripts

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rubymine

I am using selenium webdriver with Ruby and Scite editor/interpretor(OPTION A). I am planning to install cucumber with RubyMine IDE (OPTION B). I wanted to know can the scripts I create using OPTION A can be transferred/re-used to OPTION B since both are in Ruby ?

Comment: Why do you think the editor/IDE you write your code has a influence if you can start the ruby script?

Comment: SciTE is a text editor, and RubyMine is an IDE.  You'll get more features with RubyMine (since it's an IDE), but you can use the scripts written using SciTE.  In fact--if you already have both--you should try it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks @orde. Will it create any issues if I have both RubyMine with cucumber and Scite installed in one system ? I am asking this because  when I tired to install Rubymine in my system it messed up my installtion with existing selenium webdriver and even Rubymine did not install properly. I may have not done this in the correct way though. Any suggestions ?